# Use of 'such as themselves'?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage

Would it be correct to use the following sentence?

```
The group make for a handsome lot. And that poise of talk can only be 
found in the most opulent of beings, such as themselves.
```

I have been mulling over whether this is an acceptable way to use *'such as themselves'.* If this isn't, could any of you reframe the sentence for me?

Answer (score 1):

In formal writing, use the **reflexive pronoun** when the pronoun refers to the *subject* of the sentence:

> And *they* considered that such poise of talk can only be found in the
>   most opulent of beings, such as **themselves**.

Comment: But if this 'handsome lot' in question isn't at the locale and is being referred to by two people in a conversation? Surely then they wouldn't be talking about **themselves**.

Comment: @SamparkSharma If you say so.  It's your sentence.  But if the subject doesn't match the pronoun, then the reflexive pronoun is inapt.  "Poise" is the subject of the sentence in question.